# Command to create a rake task with some folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

```
 rails g task folder1/namespace1 task1
```

Above command will create the **task1.rake** inside **lib/tasks/task1.rake**

But, I need to keep my **task1.rake** inside **lib/tasks/folder1/task1.rake**

Comment: are you using Rubymine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rails g task` generator does not work this way.

Here are the code for the `TaskGenerator` class

```
module Rails
  module Generators
    class TaskGenerator < NamedBase # :nodoc:
      argument :actions, type: :array, default: [], banner: "action action"

      def create_task_files
        template 'task.rb', File.join('lib/tasks', "#{file_name}.rake")
      end

    end
  end
end
```

As you see the `lib/tasks` path is hardcoded and you can not pass in options to alter the path.

I think this might be a great addition to the `TaskGenerator` class.

The answer to your question is that you have to make the folders manually.

Comment: this is what i expect?